# Quel pronom utiliser pour traduire « It's not possible to translate IT » ?

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots

- *C'est **le** pas possible traduire.*
- *C'est pas possible **le** traduire.*
- *C'est pas possible traduire-**il**.*

ou comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mot à mot :

> Ce n'est pas possible de *le* traduire.

Transposé (déplacement de la négation, pour une traduction plus soutenue):

> Il est impossible de *le* traduire.

Comment: merci pour la réponse.
Porquoi non "C'est pas possible de le traduire."?

Comment: Il manque le *ne* dans votre commentaire : "Ce n'est pas ..." mais vous pourrez entendre cette formule familière dans la bouche des enfants. "C'est pas possible, c'est pas possible qui m'ait fait ça ! à moi !" [suppression du *ne* et mauvaise grammaire ensuite] est une tournure à n'utiliser que pour évoquer des propos argotiques, ou a utiliser dans des dialogues humoristique, mais surtout pas à l'écrit (à moins de le remettre dans son contexte).

Comment: merci beaucoup ;)

Comment: Pour nuancer le propos de cl-r (que je rejoins totalement sur l'ensemble), la négation "tronquée" *C'est pas possible de ...* n'est pas utilisée que par les enfants. C'est la version relachée et informelle qu'on entend à l'oral bien plus souvent que la version complète, quel que soit l'age des interlocuteurs.

Answer (score 6):

Cette périphrase est aussi lourde qu'inutile. La traduction qui s'impose est:

> C'est intraduisible.

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, je favoriserait *C'est impossible à traduire* plutôt que *impossible de le traduire* tant que le verbe est seul. Dès qu'il s'agit d'une clause infinitive, par contre, il faut effectivement revenir à *de* (par ex. *C'est possible/impossible de le traduire de cette manière.*).